# Raspberry Pi Zero -- C++ can't find Wire.h

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

I'm an absolute beginner with Raspberry Pi. I'm running Debian and trying to code in C++ so that I can read an I2C sensor (Grove TSYS01 temperature) connected to the GPIO pins. My code gets as far as...

#include <wire.h>

...then gives a "No such file or directory" error. Does anyone know how to specify the location of wire.h on a Raspberry Pi?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that [wire.h](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/wire) is an Arduino library.  I doubt it will exist on a Pi.

Comment: If your file system is case sensitive (which is highly likely for Debian), you need to match the case of the file name. The question title and the code snippet differ in the case of the `W`...

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! I've tried using different cases for wire.h but no luck. I also did a file search and wire.h doesn't show up, so it's likely only for the Arduino library. I'm testing my sensor with c++ code from the manufacturer, and that included wire.h. I'm thinking that I may have to find a new GPIO function library specifically for Raspbrry Pis and start from scratch with the code.

Comment: This thread should help you out. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3627/is-there-an-i2c-library

Comment: Just an update. Thanks @rabbit, your link is very helpful. There is an available Linux I2C library (#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>) and it seems to work on Debian. Or at least, I'm trying to make it work on Debian. I can get the header file to compile to an object file but I have to figure out how to link the object and main to get an executable.